# Maximum calls exceeded somehow

Tags: javascript, function

Today I (tried) created some code to create mcq questions.

The code is supposed to generate a random [codon](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/ap-biology/gene-expression-and-regulation/translation/a/the-genetic-code-discovery-and-properties), find its amino acid from the codon table/chart and display it on the document along with other (3) random wrong options.

I want to make a mcq with 4 options (1 is correct rest are wrong).

What I am trying to do below is: The computer will form a random sequence of 3 nucleotides (i.e.digits) using form() function. Variable `formed` will store a codon (eg. UCA, ACC etc.) which will be the **question**.

Now I declared array `arr` which will store the **correct answer** at 0th position.

Then I created a function generateWrongOptions() which will (is supposed to) add the other 3 *dissimilar* **wrong answers** to the array. What I tried to do here is that the function will declare a new amino acid (eg. Phe, Ile, Met etc.) which is stored as `wrong` and a new empty array `arr2`. The next loop is supposed to check if `wrong` is already present in `arr` or not; **if it is not** then it will push an element 'a' ('a' here doesn't has any meaning) in arr2, if it is then it won't. Now `if` will check if the `arr` length is equal to `arr2` which simply means if the variable `wrong` is unique or not (or is duplicate).

I wanted to create 4 options (1 was already present) hence I looped the code for i<3 times.

I found better ways to do this same task online, but those were more advanced and I couldn't understand them. Hence I'd come with my own solution (best I could've guessed).

```
const obj = {
UUU:"Phe",
UUC:"Phe",
UUA:"Leu",
UUG:"Leu",
CUU:"Leu",
CUC:"Leu",
CUA:"Leu",
CUG:"Leu",
AUU:"Ile",
AUC:"Ile",
AUA:"Ile",
AUG:"Met",
GUU:"Val",
GUC:"Val",
GUA:"Val",
GUG:"Val",

/* - */

UCU:"Ser",
UCC:"Ser",
UCA:"Ser",
UCG:"Ser",
CCU:"Pro",
CCC:"Pro",
CCA:"Pro",
CCG:"Pro",
ACU:"Thr",
ACC:"Thr",
ACA:"Thr",
ACG:"Thr",
GCU:"Ala",
GCC:"Ala",
GCA:"Ala",
GCG:"Ala",

/* - */

UAU:"Tyr",
UAC:"Tyr",
UAA:"Stop",
UAG:"Stop",
CAU:"His",
CAC:"His",
CAA:"Gln",
CAG:"Gln",
AAU:"Asn",
AAC:"Asn",
AAA:"Lys",
AAG:"Lys",
GAU:"Asp",
GAC:"Asp",
GAA:"Glu",
GAG:"Glu",

/* - */

UGU:"Cys",
UGC:"Cys",
UGA:"Stop",
UGG:"trp",
CGU:"Arg",
CGC:"Arg",
CGA:"Arg",
CGG:"Arg",
AGU:"Ser",
AGC:"Ser",
AGA:"Arg",
AGG:"Arg",
GGU:"Gly",
GGC:"Gly",
GGA:"Gly",
GGG:"Gly", 
};

const digit = ['U', 'C', 'A', 'G'];

function x() {
return Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
};

function form() {
  return digit[x()]+digit[x()]+digit[x()]
}

let formed = form();
let arr = [obj[formed]];

function generateWrongOptions() {

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  let wrong = obj[form()];
  let arr2 = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (wrong!==arr[i]){
      arr2.push('a');
    };
  if(arr2.length==arr.length){
      arr.push(wrong)
    }
  else {
      generateWrongOptions()
    };
    };
  };
};

generateWrongOptions();
for (let n of arr) {
  console.log(n)
}
```

Console returns Maximum calls exceeded;

On the other hand a similar code I wrote before creating this - as a guideline - to form an array of 4 different numbers works:

```
function x() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
}

let y = x();
let arr = [y];

function aa() {
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let z = x()
    let arr2 = [] 
 
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) 
    {
      if (z!==arr[i]) 
      {arr2.push('a')};
     }

    if (arr2.length==arr.length) 
    {arr.push(z)}

     else {aa()}  
  };
};

aa();
console.log(arr);
```

I think I can fix this code by declaring a new array of all the amino acids in the codon table (obj), but still want to know why the first code doesn't work while the latter does.

Comment: You never return anything nor change any variable that is outside of the scope of the function. You wanted to change `arr`, but you created a new variable named `arr` instead

Comment: Please format your code so that it becomes readable, with proper indentation and no unnecessary empty lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure if I understand your code correctly. However, I can see that  you have two for loops in which you forgot to create a new variable:
you used "`for (i .... )`" , and you forgot to say "`for (let i ..... )`". Another issue i noticed is the redeclaration of "arr" in the last function, which I found weird since you already declared it outside of the function scope. In addition, there is an "arr2" that was also not declared with "let" or "var" words.

Comment: It was supposed to be `arr2` instead of `arr`. `i` didn't cause a problem though. I worked on the code for sometime and found that I had misplaced the last `if else` condition; it was supposed to be outside the 2nd loop and now the code works fine. Thanks